# What Option Disables This Popup in Visual Studio Code when Working with JS Files?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: VS Code Popup]

I find this undesirable and would like to disable whatever this is. Thanks!

Comment: For the record, it's not some extension; I verified that by disabling all extensions and still seeing this whatever it is. I get what it's doing; I don't want those definitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Edit: was renamed at some point: `"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false`

For all files:

```json
"editor.parameterHints": false
```

For js:

```json
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.parameterHints": false
}
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks so much!